# Should we consider $\frac12$ as a root of $(2x-1)\sqrt{x^2-1}=0$?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

Suppose we have the equation
$$(2x-1)\sqrt{x^2-1}=0$$
In high school level math, we say it has only two roots $x=\pm1$ and $x=\frac12$ is not a root because it is not in the domain of $\sqrt{x^2-1}$.

But I'm wondering in the advanced level mathematics, where we are allowed to use complex numbers, do we consider $\frac12$ as a root or not? Since if we plug this value in the equation we get,

$$0\times\sqrt{\frac{-3}4}=0\times\frac{\sqrt3i}2=0$$

Comment: Yes, but mind that: it is very advanced.

Comment: That depends... If you are treating $f(x)=(2x-1)\sqrt{x^2-1}$ as a function from $[1,\infty)$ to $\Bbb R$ then $\frac{1}{2}$ is not in the domain and so does not count as a root.  Roots are those elements *in the domain* who make the result of the function equal to zero.  If you are treating $f(x)$ instead as a function from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb C$ then yes $\frac{1}{2}$ *is* a root.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the very good explanation.

Comment: As a rule, solutions to $f(x)=0$ are taken from the domain of $f.$ So it depends on the domain of $f(x)=(2x-1)\sqrt{x^2-1}.$ We tend to not define functions on real number with domains that have isolated points. But we *could* here define $f$ at $x=1/2,$ or we could define $f$ as a complex-valued function, and then define $f$ for all complex $x.$ So it really all depends on what you want.

Comment: The fact that if $\sqrt{~}$ is being treated as a real function that plugging in negative values results in a non-real result is a bigger issue... While true that $0$ times a complex number results in zero, the issue here is that $0$ times `undefined` is undefined.

Comment: @Etemon I believe it actually applies to odd $n$ as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless otherwise designated (by yourself or the text that you're reading), treat $$\sqrt[n]{\quad}$$ as having domain $[0,∞),$ in which case everyone agrees that it outputs the nonnegative root.

This is because otherwise, the author anyway still needs to specify how to pick the $n$th root (of multiple ones) that the symbol is meant to output. In other words, without some explanatory note, for $x\in\mathbb C{\setminus}[0,\infty),$ it is unclear which value $\large\sqrt[n]{x}$ outputs.

OP's deleted comment:

> Thanks for the help. I think you meant $\sqrt[2n]{\quad}.$

No, I did mean $\sqrt[n]{\quad}.$ For example, $\sqrt[3] {-1}$ has no definite  convention for its output value: $\displaystyle e^{i \frac\pi3}$ is as reasonable a choice as $-1;$ in fact, in complex analysis, the former is probably the more common choice.

> $$(2x-1)\sqrt{x^2-1}=0$$

Following my own advice, unless otherwise stated, I'd assume that the LHS has domain $(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty).$

Comment: Sorry I removed my comments on my post right after seeing you changed yours to an answer.

Comment: @Etemon No worries; rectified!